# Countries and population

Tags: python

If you're given a list of countries and its corresponding population, write a function that will return a random country but the higher the population of the country, the more likely it is to be picked at random.

```
import numpy as np
def randomCountry(countries, pop):
    countries = ["CUBA", "Spain", "USA","Belgium"]
    #Population in millions
    pop = [54,32,300,75]
    probabilities = pop/np.sum(pop)

    # Get the indices of the sorted probabilities
    idx_sort = np.argsort(probabilities)
    probabilities = probabilities[idx_sort]
    countries = countries[idx_sort]

    rand = np.random.choice(countries, p = np.array(pop) / np.sum(pop))
    summ = 0
    i = 0
    while(summ &lt;= rand):
        summ = summ + probabilities[i]
        i = i + 1

    return countries[i-1]
```

I am not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: @RushabhMehta, OP provided a clear problem with a reasonable attempt. Though they could have defined the exact issues they are facing in a more clear way, this at least shows that they have tried something, IMO.

Comment: What you need is similar to the concept of *Kinetic Monte Carlo* algorithm which have some probabilities of some process to happen. Using cumulative probabilities and a random number between 0 and 1, you chose a process. Higher the individual probability of a process, higher are its chances to occur. I can use that algo in your code but currently I am getting several `Type Errors` for ex. in `while` condition and in the definition of `rand`. Nevertheless, if you are interested you can have a look at the algorithm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_Monte_Carlo Feel free to ask me more

Answer (score 2):

Instead, you can use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), and use the argument `p` to define the probabilities of choosing a country based on population.

**Example**:

```
countries = ['A', 'B', 'C']
populations = [100, 25, 12]

np.random.choice(countries, p = populations / np.sum(populations))
```

**Explanation**:

`p` is the likelihood of selecting a given country. So by using `populations / np.sum(populations)`, which results in `array([ 0.72992701,  0.18248175,  0.08759124])`, you are saying: select Country `A` 72% of the time, `B` 18% of the time, and `C` 8% of the time.

Comment: Nice, but we can avoid wrapping np.array() around populations. I think.